# Can web2py list contains() be negated?

Tags: list, web2py, contains

I am trying to select a table where a certain value is not present in a reference field. Is it possible to negate the contains() method?

```
grid = SQLFORM.smartgrid(db.redaktion.projekt.contains(projektid)
```

Answer (score 0):

The negation operator in `pyDAL` queries is `~`. Also, the first argument of `smartgrid` must be a `Table` rather than a `Query`. To apply a query to a given table, use the `constraints` argument. So, it would be:

```
grid = SQLFORM.smartgrid(db.redaktion,
    constraints={'redaktion': ~db.redaktion.projekt.contains(projektid)})
```

See http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/06/the-database-abstraction-layer#Logical-operators.

Comment: thanks @Anthony, it seems now, that queries with grid other than table selects, i.e. "SQLFORM.smartgrid(db.redaktion)", result in an 'Attribute error:  
'Query' object has no attribute '_tablename''

Comment: Okay, found the answer:
SQLFORM.grid(query) OK
SQLFORM.smartgrid(table) OK
SQLFORM.smartgrid(query) WRONG!
SQLFORM.smartgrid(table, contraints={'tablename':query}) OK

Comment: Right, I was just copying your code and missed the `smartgrid` vs. `grid`. I've updated the answer to reflect the correct code.